# Custom repository in spring data (base repository and single repository) is not working when implementing both

Tags: spring, spring-data

we have a some common method that i want to available in all repository (like `fineOne` (spring boot 2.0 method signature has been change ) so we add this method in base repository and also we need some of custom method for repository specific so also implements both base and custom  )

application class:

```
    @EnableMongoRepositories(basePackages ={"com.kairos.activity.persistence.repository"},
    repositoryBaseClass = MongoBaseRepositoryImpl.class)
    public class KairosActivityApplication 


    @NoRepositoryBean
    public interface MongoBaseRepository<T, ID extends Serializable> extends MongoRepository<T, ID> {
         T findOne(ID id);
    }

    public class MongoBaseRepositoryImpl<T, ID extends Serializable>
    extends SimpleMongoRepository<T, ID> implements MongoBaseRepository<T, ID> {
        private final MongoOperations mongoOperations;
        private final MongoEntityInformation<T, ID> entityInformation;
        public MongoBaseRepositoryImpl(MongoEntityInformation<T, ID>  entityInformation,
                                  MongoOperations mongoOperations) {
            super(entityInformation, mongoOperations);
            // Keep the EntityManager around to used from the newly introduced methods.
            this.mongoOperations = mongoOperations;
            this.entityInformation=entityInformation;
        }
        @Override
        public T findOne(ID id) {
            Assert.notNull(id, "The given id must not be null!");

            return mongoOperations.findById(id, entityInformation.getJavaType(), entityInformation.getCollectionName());
        }
    }
```

and now

```
    @Repository
    public interface ActivityMongoRepository extends MongoBaseRepository<Activity, BigInteger>,CustomActivityMongoRepository {

        @Query(value="{staffId:?0,unitId:?3,disabled:false,startDate:{$gte:?1},endDate:{$lte:?2}}")
        List<ActivityQueryResult> findAllActivityBetweenDuration(Long staffIf, Date startDate, Date endDate,Long unitId);

        Long countByActivityTypeId(BigInteger activityTypeId);

    }

    public interface CustomActivityMongoRepository {

        void updatePhasesOfActivities(Long orgId, Date startDateInISO, Date endDateInISO, String phaseName, String PhaseDescription);
    }
```

Repository specific custom repository not working its method treat like normal method of main repository and give parsing error

```
    nested exception is org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property unit found for type Phase!
```

that should be working but i think when we implements base custom repository (repository specific custom implementation are ignore )

Comment: Why are you reimplementing what is already implemented by Spring Data? `findOne` is supported out-of-the-box why reimplement it? If you want to "alias" `findOne` (instead of using the `findById` which I would recommend) use a Java8 `default` method in your interface, don't make it more complex then that.

Comment: */
 <S extends T> Optional<S> findOne(Example<S> example); findOne has been modified now in lasted documentation @see QueryByExampleExecutor

Comment: */
 <S extends T> Optional<S> findOne(Example<S> example); findOne has been modified now in lasted documentation @see QueryByExampleExecutor <br/> M.Deinum we have project that was build on spring boot 1.5.6 and we used findOne(ID) every where ...Now i am Going to update this in spring boot 2.0 that will modified fineOne() and add new method findById(ID) ..but we can not changed whole application fineOne to findById()

Comment: As stated just create a `default` interface method which in turn calls the `findById`... Don't make it more complex then that. Or don't upgrade as Spring Boot 2 isn't final yet (it still is in the beta phase).

Comment: 1.Spring data modified fineOne(ID) public interface QueryByExampleExecutor<T> {<S extends T> Optional<S> findOne(Example<S> example);}  2.we have project that used fineOne(Id) now we want to implements custom base repository that have this method and make available in all repository .....its work but when i have implement custom repository for repository only  i am getting error ..please suggest me (Question is can we implements base custom repository and custom repository both  )

Comment: Where is the implementation of `updatePhasesOfActivities` supposed to come from?